# How should I name these classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, naming-conventions

I have two different group of classes which inherit from two different base classes (`Value` and `Token`).

In both groups I have classes that I would simply call `String`, `Number`, `Name`, if only their name didn't clash with the class name from the other group.

So basically I need a way to distinguish the class `String` that inherits from `Value` from the class `String` that inherits from `Token`, and I have no idea on how to do this.

I can't put them in the namespace of their base class because thy inherit from the same class they are in and the compiler gives me an "invalid use of incomplete type" error. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you name them `ValueString` and `TokenString`?

Comment: @Eli Sadoff because I didn't think about that solution until I posted this answer .-.

Comment: When I said "why don't you" I was just phrasing it like that. I didn't mean "You idiot!".

Comment: That's what namespaces are for! I can't say it enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to name them `StringValue` and `StringToken`.

You can't define them inside their base classes like:

```
struct Value
{
    struct String : Value {};
};
```

But you *can* define them *and the base class* inside a namespace:

```
namespace Value
{
    struct Base {};
    struct String:Base {};
}
```

and then refer to `Value::Base` or `Value::String`.

While I am very fond of namespaces, in this particular case, I would tend to the `StringValue` solution.

(Note:  I have used `struct` in the examples because it saves all the messing around with `public`.  For real code, you probably want to use `class`.)

Comment: Actually, technically you could put the base class outside the namespace, but you still couldn't give it the same name as the namespace - and doing so would be silly!

Comment: You can give the same name as the namespace, provided it's inside the namespace http://ideone.com/YPziDy

Comment: @vsoftco: I know - which is why I said you **can't** do that.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ooh! Inside the namespace - yes you could, but it would be awfully confusing.  Value::Value::Value would be the constructor!

Comment: @MartinBonner, yes. In fact, [it gets better than that](http://ideone.com/6U0bof)

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem with namespacing these.

```
struct Value {};
struct Token {};

namespace Values { struct String : Value {}; }
namespace Tokens { struct String : Token {}; }
```

should work, as should

```
namespace Values { struct Value {}; struct String : Value {}; }
namespace Tokens { struct Token {}; struct String : Token {}; }
```

One thing that won't work is

```
struct Value
{
    struct String : public Value {};
};
```

because `Value` isn't completely defined when you're trying to inherit from it.
If this is what you're doing, the solution is to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Call one `StringValue` and the other `StringToken`?